# How To Use Multiple Media Queries Within A Css Class In Less?

Tags: html, css, less

I have a less file containing a simple css class that needs to have different styles applied for various screen sizes. The following code only works on desktop (the first `@desktop` media query). Nothing happens for mobile. I have tried many variations of this syntax with no luck and haven't found anything about this in the docs. You can also see the [live demo here](https://codepen.io/JimTheMan_1470597425/pen/zMrpoR) (notice how if you stretch the screen wider than 1024px the div turns orange, but it does not turn red or green when smaller than 1024px as it should). Thanks.

html

```
<div class="derp">
Hello
</div>
```

less

```
@desktop-min-width:         1024px;
@phone-max-width:           768px;

@desktop: ~"only screen and (min-width: @{desktop-min-width})";
@tablet: ~"only screen and (min-width: @{phone-max-width}) and (max-width: @{desktop-min-width}";
@phone: ~"only screen and (max-width: @{phone-max-width})";

@appHeight:     749px;
@appWidth:      421px;

.derp {
  @media @desktop {
      background-color: orange;
    }

  @media @tablet {
      background-color: red;
    }

  @media @phone {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with

```
@tablet: ~"only screen and (min-width: @{phone-max-width}) and (max-width: @{desktop-min-width}";
```

Remove it for a moment, and you will see green background is displayed for phone screen.

You need to add ")" for a @tablet at the end